# Why is String.Contains case-insensitive in this query?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working my way through [this ASP MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view). This page of the tutorial deals with writing a simple "search" page. The controller contains this method:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString) 
{           
     var movies = from m in db.Movies 
                  select m; 

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)) 
    { 
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString)); 
    } 

    return View(movies); 
}
```

According to MSDN, [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) is case-sensitive. But when I navigate to `[website url]/Movies/SearchIndex?searchString=mel`, it returns a movie with the title `Melancholia` as a result. If I inspect the controller method in the debugger, `searchString` is `mel` (in lower case) as expected.

Why does `String.Contains` match this title case-insensitively?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using `Linq to entities` the query is done by the SQL Server. Your Lambda expression is translated to an SQL query, so whether or not it is case sensitive depends on the server configuration.

If you'd like to change your SQL Server collation and make it case sensitive, please see this page:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/